# Take first event from long file and transform to wide file

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

Ciao, I have several rows for each student.
ID is equal to the student ID, DAY_DISCIPLINE_A is equal to the day of the school year that the student was disciplined for "A" and DAY_DISCIPLINE_B is equal to the day of the school year that the student was disciplined for "B"

This is my replicating example

```
HAVE <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                   DAY_DISCIPLINE_A=c(12,15,NA,10,NA,NA,NA,NA,16,NA,NA,NA),
                   DAY_DISCIPLINE_B=c(NA,NA,NA,10,11,12,NA,14,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

My goal is to create new data frame whereby every student has 1 row shown here as an example

```
WANT <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4),
                   DAY=c(12,10,14,-99),
                   DISCIPLINE=c("A","B","B","none"))
```

In this example every student has 1 row; DAY equals to the day of the FIRST discipline a student received whether it is A or B (the lowest value of DAY) and DISCIPLINE equals to the type of DISCIPLINE. Now in other words; I am aiming to create a new data file whereby each ID has one row and I capture the students first DISCIPLINE and report the TYPE and the DAY of that DISCIPLINE. If no DISCIPLINE is reported than DAY should be -99 and DISCIPLINE should be "none". If DISCIPLINE A and B happen on the same day then I report that DAY and set DISCIPLINE equal to B for all ties.

Comment: Where does the -99 come from?

Comment: If there is no discipline than I set it to -99

Answer (score 1):

Taking advatage of fact that 'B' comes after 'A', here is a simple way of doing this with `dplyr` and `tidyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

WANT <- gather(HAVE, key = "DISCIPLINE", value = "DAY", DAY_DISCIPLINE_A, DAY_DISCIPLINE_B) %>%
  arrange(ID, DAY, desc(DISCIPLINE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  mutate(
    DISCIPLINE =  ifelse(is.na(DAY), "none", substring(DISCIPLINE, 16, 16)),
    DAY = ifelse(is.na(DAY), -99, DAY)
  )

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID DISCIPLINE   DAY
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1  1.00 A           12.0
2  2.00 B           10.0
3  3.00 B           14.0
4  4.00 none       -99.0
```

mutate statement is only needed for cosmetic changes and can be avoided if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With data.table...

```
library(data.table)
# transform to long form, sort by DAY, drop duplicates
res = melt(setDT(HAVE), "ID", variable.name="DISCIPLINE", value.name="DAY")[order(DAY, -DISCIPLINE), .SD[1], keyby=ID]

# overwrite DISCIPLINE if DAY is blank    
res[is.na(DAY), DISCIPLINE := NA][]


   ID       DISCIPLINE DAY
1:  1 DAY_DISCIPLINE_A  12
2:  2 DAY_DISCIPLINE_B  10
3:  3 DAY_DISCIPLINE_B  14
4:  4             <NA>  NA
```

For translation to dplyr + tidyr, see `?gather`, `?arrange`, `?distinct`.

For analysis in R, you should use NA instead of custom missing-data codes ("none", -99). If you need to do it, though (eg, printing to Excel), the last line above shows how it could be done.

If you want to clean up the DISCIPLINE column to only show A and B, there's...

```
patt = "^DAY_DISCIPLINE_(\\w+)$"
res[DISCIPLINE %like% patt, DISCIPLINE := sub(patt, "\\1", DISCIPLINE)][]

   ID DISCIPLINE DAY
1:  1          A  12
2:  2          B  10
3:  3          B  14
4:  4       <NA>  NA
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out the `gather` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with `tidyverse`, first we transform to long, then summarize by the min value. Then filter to where `value == min(value)`, then create `DISCIPLINE`, finally, and this is a little "hackey", because we take the `max` of a character vector, we select `B` if it exists, otherwise `A`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

melt(HAVE,id = "ID") %>% group_by(ID, variable) %>% 
  summarize(value= min(na.omit(value))) %>% 
  filter(value == min(value)) %>% 
  mutate(DISCIPLINE = substr(variable, 16,16)) %>% 
  filter(DISCIPLINE == max(DISCIPLINE)) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(value == Inf,-99,value)) %>%
  select(-variable)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID value DISCIPLINE
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
1     1    12 A         
2     2    10 B         
3     3    14 B         
4     4   -99 B
```